# export PATH permanently

Tags: bash, scripting, environment-variables, path

I have exported the PATH but once I switch to a different terminal or reboot Debian, $PATH is reset. Here are the steps I take:

```
~$ vim scripts.sh

#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello"
```

I save it as `mybash.sh` and chmod with 755. Then I move it to my `/root/scripts` directory.

Then:

```
~$ export PATH=$PATH:~/root/scripts
```

and it works, but once I reboot Debian, close or switch into another terminal, `mybash.sh` cannot be called.

Why doesn't it store PATH permanently?

Comment: You might want to prepend rather than append.

Comment: Why don't you place your script in `/usr/local/sbin`, which is included in root's PATH ?

Answer (score 3):

You can add the line to the `/etc/enviroment` file like this:

```
PATH=$PATH:~/root/scripts
```

or

Edit your `~/.bashrc` and add your line here like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/root/scripts
```

Comment: No. You misspelled `/etc/environment`, the syntax you used doesn't work there (variable expansion only works in shell scripts, this is not a shell script), and `.bashrc` only works partially (it sets the variable only in programs launched from a terminal). None of this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `~/.bashrc` file and add your `export PATH` line to it.

Comment: No. `.bashrc` only works for programs launched from a terminal.

Comment: @Gilles, I quote from the question: "...into another terminal...", and therefor do not understand your comment. Can you please clarify your comment?

Comment: @Lambert `.bashrc` is only read in a terminal. So modifying `PATH` there will only take effect in programs that are launched via a terminal. That takes care of the specific example where the program is launched from a terminal, but not of the general case where the program is launched from somewhere else.

Comment: @Gilles, thanks for your explanation. The OP asked how to set the PATH variable permanently for new terminals so the answer to that is, in my opinion, still valid. I agree that you can not rely on it in all cases (ie. when calling from a custom binary started from the desktop, of using a different shell like zsh) but in this case it is obvious that bash is being used and that the script is called from a terminal window.